# Nice regex for cleaning up space separated digits in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Disclaimer - This is not a homework question. Normally I wouldn't ask something so simple, but I can't find an elegant solution.

What I am trying to achieve -

Input from OCR: "0 1 loren ipsum 1 2 3 dolor sit 4 5 6 amet -7 8 9 1- date 13 06 2022"
Parsed output: "01 loren ipsum 123 dolor sit 456 amet -7891- date 13 06 2022"

Essentially remove spaces from in between digits. However there are caveats like that preceding digits are single character long (to avoid stuff like dates). For a date like "1 1 1970" though it's fine if it gets converted to "11 1970" since it doesn't violate the single character principle.

The most decent regex I could think of was `(.*?\D)\d( \d)+`. However this doesn't work for numbers at the beginning of the string. Also search and replace is fairly complicated with this regex (I can't do a `re.subn` with this).

Can anyone think of an elegant Python based solution (preferably using regex) to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?<=\b\d)\s+(?=\d\b)")
>>> regex.sub("", "0 1 loren ipsum 1 2 3 dolor sit 4 5 6 amet -7 8 9 1- date 13 06 2022")
'01 loren ipsum 123 dolor sit 456 amet -7891- date 13 06 2022'
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\b\d) # Assert that a single digit precedes the current position
\s+       # Match one (or more) whitespace character(s)
(?=\d\b)  # Assert that a single digit follows the current position
```

The `sub()` operation removes all whitespace that matches this rule.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can capture and skip the date like format or the digits, and match 1+ whitespace chars in between digits to remove.

In the replacement use the capture groups.

```
\b(\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4})\b|(\d+)\s+(?!\D|\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4}\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4})\b` Capture a date like pattern in **group 1**
- `|` Or
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars (that will be removed)
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right of the current position is not

  - `\D` Match a non digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4}\b` Match the date like pattern
- `)` Close the negative lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qvnfSN/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(\b\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4})\b|(\d+)\s+(?!\D|\d{1,2}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4}\b)"
s = "0 1 loren ipsum 1 2 3 dolor sit 4 5 6 amet -7 8 9 1- date 13 06 2022"
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\1\2", s)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
01 loren ipsum 123 dolor sit 456 amet -7891- date 13 06 2022
```

Comment: One caveat I could think of here is that it would potentially remove spaces between digits and a valid date-format...e.g: `test 1 2 3 13 7 2022` turn into `test 12313 7 2022`. You could use a negative lookahead at the end `\s+(?!\D|\d\d?\s+\d\d?\s+\d{4}\b)`

Comment: @JvdV Oh my, you are totally right....good catch, thanks!